# How does the get function evaluate an argument differently with and without quotes ' '

Tags: r, variables, naming-conventions

I am trying to understand the different pitfalls of using assign() and get().
One example where get() will evaluate seemingly same objects differently is shown below.
To start, I assign a string 'This is: ALPHABET' to the elements of names.foo

```
names.foo <- letters
values.foo <- LETTERS
for (i in 1:length(names.foo)){
assign(names.foo[i], paste("This is: ", values.foo[i]))
}
```

And when i run get('names.foo') i get the original vector as expected

```
get('names.foo')
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"
```

But when i run get(names.foo), the same command as above but without quotes, i get what seems to be the value assigned to the first element of the vector names.foo in the for loop.

```
get(names.foo)
[1] "This is:  A"
```

Does this mean that the first element which was assigned in the for loop also has the name names.foo ? What exactly is get() doing differently in the 2 cases ?

Comment: By `assign(names.foo[i], paste("This is: ", values.foo[i]))`, you are doing something like `a <- 'This is: a'; b <- 'This is: b'; ...`. By  `get(names.foo)` you are actually getting only the variable named as the first value of `names.foo`, i.e., `get('a')`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the respective help pages, you can see that `get` and `assign` are designed to take the variable name given as a character string.  So the command

```
get('names.foo')
```

is correct.  To understand all the intricacies of this, I would recommend reading **Advanced R**, by Hadley Wickham, available for free here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/, with specific focus on the chapter regarding expressions.